# jQuery doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've made this jQuery script quite basic really, but yet it fails to work in IE, but works in every other browser have tried it in; chrome, opera, safari and Firefox.

I've uploaded the script so you can take a look

oops wrong url

http://ddart.isgreat.org/test2/
this is the right one

the code is following

```
$(function () {
    $('#uploadfile').click(function(){
        document.file.submit();
    });
    $('#upload ul li a.size').click(function(){
        if($('li#content').width() == 50){
            $('li#content').animate({
                        width:"540px"
            }, 1000,function(){
                $('#upload img[width=17]').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                    $('#upload img[width=17]').attr('src','images/arrow_left.png');
                    $('#file').fadeIn();
                    $('#upload img[width=17]').fadeIn();
                });
            });
        }else{
            $('#file').fadeOut(function() {
                $('li#content').animate({
                            width:"50px"
                }, 1000,function(){
                    $('#upload img[width=17]').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                        $('#upload img[width=17]').attr('src','images/arrow_right.png');
                        $('#upload img[width=17]').fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        };
            return false;
    });
});
```

all help I can get is very much appreciated.

Comment: We can't access your localhost to view the web page... A fragment of the HTML would help to debug..

Comment: I've updated the link accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh you need to prevent the event of the link when clicked.

Amend this

```
$('#upload ul li a.size').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I updated the link so it should work.
Well it doesnt work in ie8 that's the weirdest part
I've tried to add alert just after the $(function () {}) call but nothing happens where as i get 100 alerts in all other browsers

Comment: lol you'll never guess what the error was... 
changed
<script language="javascript" type="application/javascript"
to
<script type="text/javascript"

Comment: haha wow, had me stumped. Good catch, was about to say sounds like something more fundamentally wrong with :)

Comment: thx for the help anyways appreciate it alot for taking your time